# What is the total differential of the Gibbs Free Energy?

Tags: thermodynamics

What is the total differential of the Gibbs Free Energy as a function of its natural variables including the molar mass of a particular substance for a system consisting of a mixture of compounds?

I know the differential of the Gibbs Free Energy is
$$dG=Vdp-SdT$$
Would the function including the molar mass of a mixture of compounds be.
$$dG=\sum_{i}\frac{n_idm_i}{p_i}-SdT $$
where i is the different components of the mixed compound.

Comment: Are you familiar with the term chemical potential?

Comment: Thanks I wasn't but gave it a google and I can answer the question now.

Comment: Then please do...